# Remove else statement from list comprehensions

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

Why won't it not, not letting me use a else statement? When I run this code it's giving me this error SyntaxError: expected 'else' after 'if' expression, but I simply don't want to return anything after the if statement

```
x = ["x" if "x" in letter for letter in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want to do is to *filter* the list, rather than to *map* each value to a different value. The syntax for that is to place an `if` clause at the *end* of the list comprehension:

```
["x" for letter in s if "x" in letter]
```

At this position in a list comprehension, `if` has a special meaning: the subsequent expression is used for filtering, so that the comprehension returns only those elements that satisfy the condition (and there can be no `else`). The condition is evaluated with the *original* value of the item, but you can still do mapping (as you do, since you're using `"x"` instead of `letter`).

In your original attempt, you used `if` in the mapping expression (which says *what* you want each result element to be). There, it is interpreted as a conditional expression that must have an `else`.

By the way, if `s` is a string, so that `letter` is a single-character string, you should use `letter == "x"` instead of `"x" in letter`. The latter works, but kinda by accident (because Python represents individual characters as strings with length one), and looks confusing because the right hand side of `in` is usually a "full" string or a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Two main parts of list comprehensions are : *condition* part and *expression* part.

Here is the syntax:

```py
[expression for member in iterable if condition]
```

in *condition* part, you can not use `else`. Think of it as a filter. Move it to the end so that it acts like a filter:

```py
x = ["x" for letter in s if "x" in letter]
```

But in expression part you can have any valid Python expression.

for example a **conditional expression** as the *expression* part which is:

```py
a = <on_true> if <condition> else <on_false>
```

So you need to have the else part in *expression* part of the list comprehension because the expression part is indeed a conditional expression and the conditional expression need `else`.